java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'
Estoy actualizando mi aplicación de android a Kotlin, utilizándo SDK API 35 y Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2.
En algunas ocaciones tengo este error que provoca el cierre inesperado de la app.
Es solo en algunas ocasiones, pero no he podido identificar a que se debe.
Por favor algún feedback de alguien que haya actualizado apps con esta nueva forma de incluir las librerías en kotlin.
Detalle del Logcat:
2024-11-11 13:37:01.859 14331-14625 GoogleApiManager        com.google.android.gm                E  Failed to get service from broker.  (Ask Gemini)
                                                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3242)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3209)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3151)
                                                                                                        at amxe.a(:com.google.android.gms@244337038@24.43.37 (260800-693941914):36)
                                                                                                        at amvl.z(:com.google.android.gms@244337038@24.43.37 (260800-693941914):143)
                                                                                                        at amcs.run(:com.google.android.gms@244337038@24.43.37 (260800-693941914):54)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                                        at bskq.mC(:com.google.android.gms@244337038@24.43.37 (260800-693941914):1)
                                                                                                        at bskq.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@244337038@24.43.37 (260800-693941914):5)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85)
2024-11-11 13:37:02.136   582-744   IPCThreadState          system_server                        W  Sending oneway calls to frozen process.
2024-11-11 13:37:02.136   582-744   IPCThreadState          system_server                        W  Sending oneway calls to frozen process.

Archivo build.gradle.kts (Module)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.googleService)

}

android {
    namespace = "com.aplicacion.miaplicacion"
    compileSdk = 35


    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.aplicacion.miaplicacion"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 128
        versionName = "18"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.runtime.android)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.process)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    //Almcenamiento en Preferencias:
    implementation(libs.androidx.preference.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.preference)

    //Google Ads:
    implementation(libs.play.services.ads.lite)

    //Google Ads al abrir la app:
    implementation(libs.messagingPlatform)
    implementation(libs.multidex)

    //Google Firebase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS4qPXhru9M
    implementation(libs.firebaseAnalytics)

    //Google Billing: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/
    implementation (libs.billing)

}

Archivo build.gradle.kts (Project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.googleService) apply false

}

Versiones de librerías archivo libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.6.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.2"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
preferenceKtx = "1.2.1"
playServicesAdsLite = "23.5.0"
preference = "1.2.1"
googleServiceVersion="4.4.2"
firebaseAnalyticsVersion="22.1.2"
billingVersion="7.1.1"
runtimeAndroid = "1.7.4"
messagingPlatformVersion="3.1.0"
multidexVersion="2.0.1"
lifecycleProcess = "2.8.7"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
androidx-preference-ktx = { group = "androidx.preference", name = "preference-ktx", version.ref = "preferenceKtx" }
play-services-ads-lite = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-ads-lite", version.ref = "playServicesAdsLite" }
androidx-preference = { group = "androidx.preference", name = "preference", version.ref = "preference" }
firebaseAnalytics = {group="com.google.firebase" , name="firebase-analytics", version.ref="firebaseAnalyticsVersion"}
billing = {module="com.android.billingclient:billing", version.ref="billingVersion"}
androidx-runtime-android = { group = "androidx.compose.runtime", name = "runtime-android", version.ref = "runtimeAndroid" }
messagingPlatform = {group="com.google.android.ump", name="user-messaging-platform", version.ref="messagingPlatformVersion"}
multidex = {group="androidx.multidex", name="multidex", version.ref="multidexVersion"}
androidx-lifecycle-process = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-process", version.ref = "lifecycleProcess" }


[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
googleService={id="com.google.gms.google-services" , version.ref="googleServiceVersion"}

Agradezco ayuda para solucionar esta excepcion "SecurityException".
Saludos.
